# Anti-Aliasing and the Fourier Transform, Gonzalez Digital Image Processing

Tags: fourier-transform

In Gonzalez book Digital Image Processing, section 4.34 (third edition), he writes:

> Unfortunately, except for some special cases mentioned blow, aliasing
> is always present in sampled signals because, even if the original
> sampled function is band-limited, infinite frequency components are
> introduced the moment we limit the duration of the function, which we
> always have to do in practice.
>
> For example, suppose that we want to limit the duration of a
> band-limited function $f(t)$ (i.e. a function whose Fourier transform
> is non-zero only on a closed interval of range of frequencies), to an
> interval say $[0, T]$. We can do this by multiplying $f(t)$ by the
> function
>
> $h(t)= 1 $ if $t \in [0,T]$, and is $0$ otherwise.
>
> Then from the convolution theorem we know that the transform of this
> product $h(t)f(t)$ is the convolution of the transforms of the
> functions. Even if the transform of $f(t)$ is band-limited, convolving
> it with $F(h(t))=H(\mu)$ will yield a result with frequency components
> that are infinite.

This very last statement is what I am not sure about. If the Fourier transform of $f$ is band-limited, then outside of a closed interval, the transformed function will be $0$, and so I am not sure for which frequency components the convolution of the transforms will have infinite frequency. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in order to obtain the Fourier transform of the windowed time domain signal $f(t)h(t)$, you need to convolve the Fourier transforms of $f(t)$ and $h(t)$. We know that the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is zero outside some interval (because $f(t)$ is band-limited). However, since $h(t)$ is time-limited, i.e., it is zero outside some time interval, we know that its Fourier transform cannot be band-limited. For this specific example of a rectangular window $h(t)$, we know that the corresponding Fourier transform is a sinc function. Convolving any function with a sinc function results in a function that extends from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Consequently, the Fourier transform of the windowed signal $f(t)h(t)$ also extends from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Consequently, the signal $f(t)h(t)$ cannot be band-limited.

In sum, a band-limited signal cannot be time-limited, and a time-limited signal cannot be band-limited. Note, however, that you cannot conclude that a signal is band-limited if it is *not* time-limited and vice versa. There are signal that are neither time-limited nor band-limited.

Comment: "Convolving any function with a sinc function results in a function that extends from −∞ to +∞". I think this is the heart of my conusion. Can you elaborate on this, because it seems to me that we would be integrating the FT of $f(t)$ weighted by a translation of the sync in some interval, and zero elsewhere? I don't see why there would be non=zero values in the entire range of $\mathbb R$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: * non-zero, typo.

Comment: @IntegrateThis: Convolving a rectangle with a sinc is basically just a moving average of the sinc function, hence extending from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.